# Value of type 'Data?' has no member 'base64EncodedStringWithOptions'

Tags: ios, swift3, nsstringencoding

Here I am encoding my string but it gives an error stated above. What I had done is:

```
let plainData = (password)?.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
let base64String = plainData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
```

It gives me an error on the second line of code.
If anyone can help!

Comment: `if let plainData = password?.data(using: .utf8),
        let base64String = plainData.base64EncodedData() {`

Answer (score 9):

You need to use `base64EncodedString()` function of NSData.

`let base64String = plainData?.base64EncodedString()`

This works with Swift 3.0

Answer (score 4):

Actually with update of swift version it gives an error. We can do something like:

```
let plainData = (password)?.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
let base64String = plainData?.base64EncodedData(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
```

It solved my problem.

Comment: You can write it a little bit shorter: `let plainData = password?.data(using: .utf8)` `let base64String = plainData?.base64EncodedData()`